# How to check if list element is present or not

Tags: selenium, testing, appium

I have page object I want to know how to write a method if no elemenets are displayed or present pass the test case  otherwise keep testing.

I'm trying to figure out or we should do try and catch or assertTrue.

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "lakjdfaj");
List<MobileElement> texts;

public boolean doesNotPresent() {
Boolean notDisplayed = texts.isEmpty();
if(notDisplayed){
return true;
} else {
return false; 
}
```

Comment: So, do you get any errors when running this?

Comment: Would you use this method or assertTrue way is better? I want to  know how to do it better way?

Comment: It basically does the same thing. Having an explicit assert statement would make it more readable, though.

Comment: I am wondering what the rest of your test case looks like as I think the answer should depend on that. I’m curious in what situation you want to pass the test if no elements are present but also move on to perform some test if they are.

Comment: if no elements are present test should be passed finished but if there is an element exist test should keep going not fail. When there is not element this test keeps going to next step.

Comment: @alexhacki : check the size of the list if size greater than 0, It means list is `EMPTY`.

Answer (score 3):

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "lakjdfaj");
List<MobileElement> texts;
```

// verify when no elements are shown

```
@Test      
public boolean verifyEmptyTexts() {
assertEquals(0,texts.size());
}
```

// verify when elements are shown, 2nd elements is verified here

```
@Test 
public boolean verifyTexts() {
assertEquals("textToVerify",texts.get(1).getText());
}
```

Comment: Always, always, always add a message to your asserts indicating what you are verifying. That way when you get the results, you will see that it failed and have a better idea what you were checking, e.g. `assertEquals(0, texts.size(), "Verify that the texts elements are not on the page");` or whatever.

Comment: I agree with @JeffC 100%, in fact if you do not add text, your console or report will only list "assertion error" instead of a meaningful message explaining the anticipated error..

Comment: Something like this is the only solution that would make sense to me. Your question is attempting to test two mutually exclusive expected results and is best written as two test, each with one of the expected results.

Comment: @JeffC 
I believe your raised point is correct, I missed that point as I just focused on the problem statement provided by questioner, yes it is a good point to write message in assert statement for better readability in logs in case of assert failure, thanks for pointing that.